# .Rows.Count always returns -1 even if record in database already exists?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Basically I want to check, using c#, if there is a username in the database already existing. If there is not-it must be created.
Below is the code that is doing exactly that(only the checking part matters in my opinion, but I have added the code for the adding part anyways)

Problem is that no matter what-if it exists or not, it always returns -1

```
public Boolean checkUser()
        {

            var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=book_library;user=root;password=root2");

            var table = new DataTable();

            connection.Open();

            string checkUsernameQuery = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = 'usernameInputField.Text'";

            var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(checkUsernameQuery, connection);

            //command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usernameInputField.Text;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is the adding part(just adding it, but it is not too related with the problem)

```
 private void registerIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkUser();

            var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=book_library;user=root;password=root2");

            connection.Open();

            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (username, password, email) VALUES ('" + usernameInputField.Text + "','" + passwordInputField.Text + "','" + emailInputField.Text + "')";

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

            command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usernameInputField.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordInputField.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailInputField.Text;

            if (checkUser())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This username already exists!");
            }
            else
            {

                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                }
            }

            connection.Close();

        }
```

Comment: You need to check again how command Parameters are actually used. Both in the `SELECT` and `INSERT` query.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = 'usernameInputField.Text'"` C# is not php, variable names do not get expanded within a string. Btw, the whole checking is unnecessary. Just create a unique index on the username field and check for constraint violation error message after executing the insert.

Comment: That is also a very weird way to compose SQL - you glue in control names *and* add parameters.  Just use parameters.  Storing passwords as plain text will also get you fired in the real world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections and Commands are disposable so you should put them inside `using` blocks to deterministically clean up resources.

If you just want to know if something exists, you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead of using a heavy-weight adapter.

Then just return the result of the expression `!= null` to get your boolean that indicates if the user is there or not.

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=book_library;user=root;password=root2"))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    string checkUsernameQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 username FROM accounts WHERE username = @p1";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@p1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usernameInputField.Text;

    var user = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    return user != null;
}
```